# Why can't I access my mariadb after installing homebrew?

Tags: mariadb

I just installed homebrew and mariadb via brew.
For some reason, get an error when trying to access the database.
If leave the password as empty, which is normally the default, it gives an error, and if I try to use the rot password it also gives an error.

Here the result I am getting:

```
➜  ~ brew services list
Name    Status  User  Plist
mariadb started refix /Users/refix/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
php     started refix /Users/refix/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
➜  ~
➜  ~
➜  ~
➜  ~ sudo mysql -uroot
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
➜  ~ sudo mysql -uroot
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
➜  ~
```

How do I access my db?

Comment: You don't need to use `sudo` to use `mysql` after installing with homebrew

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ the result is the same, with/without sudo. The sudo was actually one of my attempts to get access to the db

Comment: Clearly, the answer to your question as stated (_Why can't I access my mariadb_) is: because you are entering the wrong password. Now, if you wanted to ask instead how you could reset a MariaDB user password, you'd find plenty of existing answers on this site.